# Looking for a free .NET ORM/BL-tool with reusability in mind

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, orm

The problem is that I need to create extendible and reusable business layer. I.e. I want to create basic BL objects for user management, mail subsystem, etc. once and then extend the model with task-specific BL objects.

Also, I want to place these common BL objects into separate assembly and be able to use them in relations with task-specific BL objects.

As far as I know, you can't make it with Entity Framework, cause you can't break model description into multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [nhibernate](http://www.nhibernate.com/)?